# Quiero comprobar que el número de espacios que hay en una cadena es 2 en javascript

Tags: javascript, contador

Tengo que pedir en un prompt el nombre y apellidos de una persona, para verificar que se han introducido bien miro que el número de espacios sea dos, lo tengo que hacer con un bucle for, y no se en que me equivoco, gracias.

```
var nombreCompleto = parseInt(prompt('Introduce nombre y apellidos'));
var contador = 0;
var espacio = 'a';
for (var i = 0; i < nombreCompleto.length; i++) {
    if (nombreCompleto[i]==espacio) {
        contador++;
        console.log(contador);
        if(contador == 2) {
    document.write(nombreCompleto);}
    else{nombreCompleto = parseInt(prompt('Introduce nombre y apellidos',null));}
    }
}
```

Comment: He publicado una respuesta, pero quiero comentar... ¿Que ocurre si el nombre es compuesto ... o los apellidos? Por si no lo has tenido en cuenta. ¿Por que le haces `parseInt` a el `String` del input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Metodo [.match()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/match)**

> El método match() se usa para obtener todas las ocurrencias de una expresión regular dentro de una cadena.

```js
var nombreCompleto = prompt('Introduce nombre y apellidos');
var espacios = nombreCompleto.match(/ /g).length;
console.log("Espacios: "+espacios)

if(espacios == 2){
  //Tiene 2 espacios
}
```

Comment: Deberías usar la función trim() para quitar los espacios que puedan haber al inicio o al final del string ejemplo: var espacios = nombreCompleto.match(/ /g).trim().length;

Comment: `nombreCompleto.trim().match(/ /g).length` mas bien... Gracias por la sugerencia. He estado dudando si ponerlo o no, pero ahora queda reflejado en los comentarios :)